# How do I place fingering instructions under a string's number?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm engraving a guitar score and I would like to notate the harmonic frets under the string number, as it is done in this example:

[image]

To do this, I'm using \string and -fingering notation as it appears in the [documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-fretted-strings#string-number-indications), plus custom shorcuts to make the use of `\set FingeringOrientations` and other instructions easier, as it is shown in this [example](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/93/lily-3f342724.ly). But this isn't working for me when using both string numbers and fingerings, as the following compilable example:

```
\version "2.24.1"
\language "english"

%%shorcuts
hh = \override NoteHead.style = #'harmonic-mixed % harm head
nh = \revert NoteHead.style % normal head
hc = \markup \left-align { \draw-circle #0.3 #0.15 ##f } % harm circle

sfol = \set fingeringOrientations = #'(left) % FINGER LEFT !!!

snol = \set stringNumberOrientations = #'(left)  % number left
arm = \markup \left-align { \fontsize #-2 { "arm." } }

%% example
example = \relative c' {
  \clef "treble_8"
  \snol \sfol %% USES \SFOL TO SHOW FINGERING AT THE LEFT
  r8 \hh bf4.-7\6^\hc^>^\arm 
}

%% silly score block
\score { <<
    \new Staff \example
      >>
    \layout {
      \context {
        \Staff
        \override Fingering.staff-padding = #'()
      }
    }
}
```

Has the following output:

[image: Output from the example: fingering instruction is not modified]

If I change the value of stfol to `\set fingerOrientations = #'(x)`, where `x` is any other orientation as written text (right, down, up), it doesn't work either: nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the commands for finger orientations and string numbering orientations only work in a chord construct (see [Fingering instructions — Controlling the placement of chord fingerings](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/inside-the-staff#fingering-instructions)).

To get around this, you can treat a single note as a chord and wrap it in single chevrons (`<` & `>`).  Place the string number and finger number inside the chord structure, and place the note value outside:  `<bf -7 \6>4`.  Then both `\sfol` and `\snol` will work as expected.

The extra offsets can be altered with `-\tweak extra-offset #'(x . y)`.

You can use `\flageolet` instead of (or as your definition of) `\hc`.  And there is a command for fermatas too: `\fermata`.

```
    \sfol
    \snol
    \hh
        <bf
            -\tweak extra-offset #'(-0.7 . 0) 
                -7
            -\tweak extra-offset #'(1 . 2) 
                \6
        >4
        \flageolet
        ->
        \fermata
        \sfz
```

[image: Finger number and string number placed to the left of the note.]